# Win8 Frame.Navigate to another folder

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8

I have code working to pass users from page to page within a Windows 8 desktop application using the `Frame.Navigate` method:

```
this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(BasicPage1));
```

However if I try to navigate to a page in a subfolder (or in my case, two levels down: /categories/category-name/BasicPage1), it doesn't find the page and blows up.

I've already tried:

```
this.Frame.Navigate(new Uri("BasicPage1", UriKind.Relative));
```

but I get an invalid argument error

> Cannot convert from 'System.Uri' to 'System.Type'

I'm totally new to Windows 8 apps, but I've seen that the Navigate Uri has been discontinued in Win8?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unlike Windows Phone Frame.Navigate does not take a URI. Instead it takes the type of the page to which you want to navigate. If the names of classes in varying folders are identical, a fully qualified namespace solves the issue.